# show and hide div to change content of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I trying to change the content of my webpage using query. I have the following code, like this:

```
<div class="container" id="index">
  <div class="table-responsive container selecoes" >
      <table class="table">
          <tbody id="selecaoList">
            <td>
            <a href="#selecoes" data-identity="1">Brasil</a>
            </td>
          </tbody>
     </table>
</div>


<div class="container" id="selecoes">
   <p>show something</p>
<div>

...
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#selecoes" ).hide();
    $("#selecoes a").click(function() {
        $( "#index" ).hide();
        $("#selecoes").show();
    });

  });
</script>
```

When I open the page, the first `div` is shown and it´s fine but when I click in Brasil, don't replace(hide) the `<div id ="index">` to `<div id="selecoes">` to show the element `<p>`.

So I want to hide the first div and show the second div in place of the first one.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. You want to hide the first div and show the second div in place of the first one? Or you do **not** want this to happen?

Comment: Yes it´s this, I want to hide the first div and show the second div in place oh the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Set right selector on `click` function

**Step 2:** Close `div` tag of `#index`

Here is working code:

```
<div class="container" id="index">
  <div class="table-responsive container selecoes" >
      <table class="table">
          <tbody id="selecaoList">
            <td>
            <a href="#selecoes" data-identity="1">Brasil</a>
            </td>
          </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container" id="selecoes">
   <p>show something</p>
<div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#selecoes" ).hide();
    $("#selecaoList a").click(function() {
        $( "#index" ).hide();
        $("#selecoes").show();
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: It´s downs´t work. I tried to put an `alert` before `$( "#index" ).hide();`, and when I click doesn´t show anything...

Comment: I change `$("#selecaoList a")` to `$("#selecaoList")` and it works fine... Thanks

Comment: But selector `$("#selecaoList")` is not very good solution, because it will be binded on a whole element, so when you will have more elements inside of `#selecaoList`, they all will do the same event. `$("#selecaoList a")` would work well for you and when not, you can set custom id/class right on anchor and then change selector.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector for the click event is wrong. Must be:

```
$("#selecaoList a").click(function()  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The click function is on wrong selector. Use this code:

```
$("#selecaoList a").click(function () {
    $("#index").hide();
    $("#selecoes").show();
});
```